# Annotating a model with internationalized resources in a separate library in ASP.MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, data-annotations

I have a solution with two basic layers - an MVC project and a DAL library. Models are extracted into Common project which is library. MVC project has reference to Common.

How can I manage data annotations for models placed in a separate library?

When model was existing in MVC it was for instance:

```
[Required(ErrorMessageResourceType = typeof(Resources.ValidationMessages), ErrorMessageResourceName = "GeneralRequired")]
[Display(Name = "Name", ResourceType = typeof(Resources.Models.SomeModel))]
public string Name{ get; set; }
```

When I moved that model to separate library I've lost access to the resources. I can't refer to it because of circular dependency. I can't place the model in MVC project because DAL interface uses it (and if it would be in the MVC project then DAL has to refer to the MVC project which is impossible due to circular dependency).

Is there any way to use the data annotations in a presented scenario?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution is moving resources to the Common project. It won't damage the internationalization.